# How do I make amends with someone I was unfairly upset with?

Tags: customer-interactions, cars

I took my car to be serviced at the dealer (yes yes they charge a fortune but I trust them and they have every incentive to do a good job so that I'll purchase another vehicle from them.)

When I "checked in" I said the windshield wiper fluid spray wasn't working and so I was glad they were going to refill it. However when I got on the road afterward nothing came out when I tried to spray the windshield. I was mad because I paid so much and thought they didn't even refill the fluid. Then I noticed they had done a very shoddy job cleaning the car, whereas they usually do a great job. Lastly, I was annoyed they kept me waiting so long while some pushy customer got what he wanted right away whereas meek little me just said no problem no problem to delays etc.

So when I got to work I flipped the hood and saw the fluid tank was empty and looking at my bill I got really upset. I called the guy to complain and left a voicemail saying the tank was empty and I was really disappointed that they did such a poor job this time. He called me back and pushed back saying he asked the technician if he had filled the tank and he did, so maybe there was a hole in the tank or something and I should come in and have it looked at. For some reason I was very skeptical of this. He also insisted they cleaned my car thoroughly and that annoyed me more. So I just said I was unhappy about the service and he said his offer stands to have me come in and that was that. I didn't curse or anything crazy, but I was irritated.

Later that day I went to purchase some windshield wiper fluid and filled the tank. The spray still didn't work. With the help of someone I observed what was happening when the dispenser lever was pulled and the fluid was all leaking under the car instead of spraying the windshield. I traced the problem to a valve connecting the hoses and found it was cracked, so I ordered a replacement part.

Anyway, after discovering that it was a problem like he said, I felt very terrible of course. So on Monday (this happened on Friday) I called the guy and left him a voicemail saying I found the problem and I apologized for getting irritated and that they always do a great job for me and look forward to going to them in the future and apologized. But he never called me back, so now I'm worried I've burned my bridges with this place and I can't get my car serviced there anymore (it's a Volvo!) because I'm afraid they'll do a bad job or sabotage it to charge me more, basically all the reasons I prefer to pay more rather than go to third party places.

**What more can I do to make amends?**

Comment: Right now the question says "What more can I do to make amends?" - Isn't "make amends" a specific goal; if so isn't this question on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

> But he never called me back

If you want a reply, next time do it in person or over the phone.  Anything else and people are more likely to ignore you (usually non-maliciously).

> What more can I do?

General principle - focus on others.

He's probably focused on his tasks/moving on to the next thing for his job so he can get to other goals in his life.  He's used to dealing with extremely difficult customers.  This was nothing.  If you contacted him againm you'd be taking him away from what he'd rather be doing.  To focus on him, do not pursue it further since you already apologized.  Although he'll never know, that's very considerate toward him.

Answer (score 1):

> So I just said I was unhappy about the service and he said his offer stands to have me come in and that was that. I didn't curse or anything crazy, but I was irritated.

I currently am an intern in the customer service department at a part stocking depot for a major car company and I've overheard calls from dealers inquiring about a part while the customer is absolutely *screaming* in the background.  Don't sweat it too much about simply stating that you were unhappy with the service.  It is unlikely that the dealer really cares or even remembers this.  They have many customers, like how I have many calls, and I don't remember them unless they were *really* over the top and rude.

> What more can I do?

Go in and get the part installed.  If you remember the mechanic that was servicing you car before you can offer an apology or crack a joke (if you're confident) about how you should have listened the first time.  Having also worked in the food service industry, I greatly appreciate when someone apologies for their treatment of me and I have to congratulate you for even admitting your mistake because it does not happen often enough.